# Can I use FCM Server Key with GCM endpoint?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to test backward compatibility of FCM Server key. Can I use FCM server key with GCM endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Based from [AL.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42800020/10549958), both kinds of keys are compatible with either GCM or FCM, so long as it is a valid key. I think it should be okay.

> With all that said, so long as it is a valid Server Key, it should be
>   compatible to use for both GCM and FCM. From what I've experienced, I
>   had a Server Key originally generated from my Developer Console, and
>   after I imported the project to Firebase, the Server Key that appeared
>   in the Cloud Messaging tab was still the same (I'm not so sure if
>   that's still the case though).
>
> Nonetheless, Server Key used for GCM should still be compatible for
>   FCM.